# (Error: Invalid parameter ) How to retrieve Image from database binary -> Image (SQL Server + stored procedure) desktop app

Tags: sql-server, image, binary

I have a problem with retrieving image from binary data.

I saved an image to the database as `varbinary(max)` and it works fine, but when I want to show my image in my app, the `MemoryStream` throws an error in function `byteArrayToImage`

> Invalid Parameter

These are my functions for converting Image to binary and binary to image:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
}

public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
}
```

and this is code for adding:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "All Images|*.jpg; *.bmp; *.png";
        byte[] img = imageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);

        string CorrectFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

        String HotelName = comboBox1.Text;
        String RoomName = comboBox2.Text;

        Dictionary<string, object> parametri = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
            { "Name", CorrectFileName },
            { "RoomName1", RoomName },
            { "HotelName1", HotelName },
            { "PictureDate", img }
        };

        AppHotels.DbHelper.IzvrsiProceduru("AddPicture", parametri);       
        MessageBox.Show("Image added");
    }
```

This is code for showing the image:

(I put a breakpoint to see byte array and it seems fine! `ByteArr` returns byte[26])

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        String HotelName = comboBox3.Text;

        Dictionary<string, object> parametri = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
          { "HotelName", HotelName }  
        };

        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        d = AppHotels.DbHelper.IzvrsiProceduru("ShowPictures", parametri);

        byte[] byteArr = GetBytes((String)d.Rows[0]["PictureDate"]);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        b.BackgroundImage = byteArrayToImage(byteArr);
        b.Height = 250;
        b.Width = 200;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
   }
```

I am sorry for this long post. And thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by using this code for getting byte array from database:

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    byte[] imgData;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(AppHotels.DbHelper.getConn()))
    {
            conn.Open();
            string cmdText = "SELECT PictureDate from dbo.Pictures ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    long bufLength = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);
                    imgData = new byte[bufLength];
                    reader.GetBytes(0, 0, imgData, 0, (int)bufLength);


                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    Button b = new Button();
                    b.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
                    b.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    b.Height = 250;
                    b.Width = 200;
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```